# Таймер не работает

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему не выводит цифры на экран

```
import time

timeLeft = 60
while timeLeft > 0:
    print(timeLeft, end='')
    time.sleep(1)
    timeLeft = timeLeft - 1

print('\a')
```

Comment: У меня все работает.

Comment: Странно у меня все работает тоже только не выводит цифры

Comment: Всё выводит...,